# Sensing Ground Faults on a High Voltage Pulser - Coupled Inductor Issue in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, current-sensing, high-side, gfci

I am building a ground-fault protected High Voltage Pulser. The pulses may be as high as 500V and as narrow as 50us (20kHz).

The question of how to create GFCI protection is proving to be a complicated decision. AC and DC ground faults must be identified. This question will deal with AC faults, but I am also interested in any info on sensing DC faults as well (high-side sense resistors are out of the question at this high voltage range).

Off-the-shelf GFCI modules are out of the question, since they're intended for household wiring. This leaves coupled inductors:
[image]
In LTSpice I have modeled a [coupled inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/schaffner-emc-inc/RB6532-50-0M2/3125493) containing three coils. My intuition tells me that L1 and L2 will form a common-mode choke. When differential current is flowing, there is no net flux in the core. However in the event of a ground fault, there will be some common current, and thus some net flux in the core. This net flux will induce a current in L3, which I intended to sense with some sort of TIA.

**I'm observing that L3 carries a current, even when there is no GND fault.** Can someone help explain what I'm missing? Also, if this is based on an existing topology, I'd love to learn its name.

Comment: Did you really mean `L_stray` to be `1.5f` (*femto*)? Also, where does `R_leak` connect to?

Comment: Run your simulation again, and show the current in L1 and L2.

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiont.png) your results, but then I guessed that `Lcm=180u` (`L_CM` in your schematic), and that `CMC_R_ser` is the series resistance of `Lcm`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen the 1.5f is a consequence of LTSpice not liking parameters that are zero. I just edited the metric prefix to f in order to essentially remove it from the circuit.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy With no GND fault the current thru L1 and L2 is 500/20 = 25 A.

Comment: @banjoeschmoe May suggest not using such low values? SPICE, in general, is a numeric colver, which means using numbers that border on numric accuracy can be a problem. Not saying this is the case, just that it may be better to shunt it with its `Rpar=1m` or lower, than use extreme values. Did you see my test? Is it the same as your schematic? If not, what needs changed? Because I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: @banjoeschmoe I was hoping to see the waveform, and if possible the waveform of I(L1) - I(L2), to see if the current on L3 matches what I would expect. Or whether I(L1)-I(L2) does indeed equal 0 in your simulation. A current peak of 8A in L3 seems to suggest something seriously amiss, but I don't know what. Hence I want more data.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the difference of I(L1) and I(L2) was zero. Thanks for the clarification though, I'll be more specific next time. See my next comment -

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen well, thanks for your sim. I just re-made my entire schematic, and now everything works as expected. I've been trying to figure out what went wrong, but still have no clue. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: @banjoeschmoe Maybe you forgot some parasitic element defined, somewhere. It's always a good idea to not rely on just `RClick` alone and, instead, use `Ctrl+RClick` to see everything that may be hidden. In this regard I miss LTspice IV.